# Ansible read_csv module:How to provide path

Tags: csv, ansible

I have a csv file as below

```
Hostname,Permission,User,Group,file
lbserver1,-rw-------,root,root,/tmp/dir1/4
lbserver2,drwx------,root,root,/tmp/dir1
lbserver3,-rw-------,root,root,/tmp/dir2/8
```

I need to use path as the key. My playbook is as below

```
  - name: read csv
    read_csv:
     path: "/tmp/test.csv"
     key: file
    register: file_details
  - name: test
    debug:
     msg: "{{file_details.dict./tmp/dir2/5.Permission}}"
```

I get error as

> "msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{file_details.dict./tmp/dir2/5'.Permission}}"

I gave quotes as well as escape char for the paths, but still no luck. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the code like below:

```yaml
    - name: test
      debug:
        msg: "{{ file_details.dict['/tmp/dir2/5'].Permission }}"
```

But then it will raise an error if the key doesn't exist which is the case in your example. In that case you may use some `default`.

```yaml
    - name: test
      debug:
        msg: "{{ file_details.dict['/tmp/dir2/5'].Permission | default('undefined') }}"
```